# Modelling football matches: alternative approaches, which is correct?

Tags: regression, logistic, poisson-distribution

I am trying to model the probability of a team winning a football match.

I am able to model this probability accurately for a given team and given opp using logistic regression. What I am unable to do (or lack the knowledge to do) is model the probability for both teams within a certain match (and the draw). For example, the sum of Team A and Team B probability will often be > 1.

I thought I could get around this by modelling the goals scored for both teams within a match, then putting estimates into a Poisson model and counting how many times team A won, how many times team B won, how many draws.

I am not sure how to express this point correctly but the range of predictions from the Poisson model was accurate i.e. dividing the model probabilities into bins, the lowest win probability within the model had the lowest win probability in the data. The problem is that the scale of predicted probabilities is only about 12% (i.e. the minimum model prediction was 32%, the max was 44%)...which seems wrong (and counter to the logistic regression model which got the scale accurate).

My first thought was that the goals scored model is incorrect i.e. it is predicting smaller goal differences between teams than occurs in reality...but if I split these predictions into bins, it appears to closely model actual goals scored...so I have no idea...

My ignorance is causing me to do something wrong here so any help appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: as there is something apparently unclear about stating what you are trying to do in the first sentence...I have two models: a logistic regression model that can tell the probability of Team A winning against Team B (not the full match probabilities, it is accurate...I am not sure why I am being told it isn't when no-one else has the data to reach that conclusion but me), a Poisson model that does calculate match probabilities (i.e. Team A win, Team B win, and draw) but produces nonsensical  probabilities (as defined above). As said, my aim is to model full match probabilities (again...Team A win, Team B win, and draw)...either I need to use a new method or I am doing something wrong with my Poisson model. Someone helpfully suggested multinomial, this doesn't work with my dataset unf...so I am thinking that the problem is that my Poisson isn't producing well-scaled probabilities (as defined above).

Comment: If the sum of the probabilities is often greater than 1, then you aren't measuring the probabilities of each team winning very accurately, are you? But without a lot more detail it's going to be very hard for anyone to answer this.  What exactly are you modeling?

Comment: As said above, I am using logistic regression to model the probability of one team winning a certain match, not each team. Again, as said above, what I want is the probability of each team winning the match and the draw. I have two models: one is the logistic regression model mentioned already and the other (which is just a "one team" model as mentioned already) and a goal estimate (which is converted into outcomes using a Poisson model). The issue with the latter, as mentioned above, is that this also produces nonsensical probabilities.

Answer (score 1):

So it sounds like you have a logistic regression model that spits out the chance of a given team winning against a given opponent.

I would re-think that approach entirely and instead treat the problem as one of classification. A match between team A and team B could be labeled as "Win for A", "Win for B", or "Draw".

In that case, your model should give you values that indeed add up to 1.

Comment: Yep, so as stated above, I have done this. What I have done instead is model the number of goals the team is expected to score against that opponent and then use this as an input to a Poisson model to come up with a distribution of scores for both sides...that way everything adds up to one. The problem is that, as said above, this method gives nonsensical values.

Comment: If you had done what I stated, the probabilities would add up to 1. You say that they don't add up to 1, so I know you have done something different. Using the Poisson model sounds like a needlessly complicated intermediate step.

Comment: I am confused...I said in the OP and in the comment that the issue isn't the probabilities adding up to 1. The reason I am using a Poisson model is because the probabilities don't add up to one using logistic regression, as you say. It isn't a complicated step because, afaik, you can't convert a goal estimate into a match outcome in any other way.

Comment: > The reason I am using a Poisson model is because the probabilities don't add up to one using logistic regression,

Yeah but before that you say that your log regression accurately predicts if a team wins against an opponent.

Comment: Okay, maybe that is unclear...although my not understanding is why I am asking this question...yes, the logistic regression works but it produces non-sensical probabilities when used to model full matches i.e. the probability of team A and team B winning will sum to >1...nonetheless, the logistic regression model is (or appears) to be accurate when modelling the probability of that team winning that match.

Comment: Yeah and what my answer suggest you do is instead of logistic regression with a binary outcome (win / doesn't win) you do multinomial logistic regression of the three outcomes (Team A wins, Team B wins, Draw). Other names of that would be softmax regression. The softmax will guarantee that your probabilities add up to 1.

Comment: Yep, I have worked through this and I am fairly sure this isn't the best solution (it is just the same problem expressed in a different way). To get the probability of two teams winning a certain match, am I correct in thinking that you would need to build features from a combination of team A and team B features? I don't want to go into exactly why but this doesn't seem like the best approach (again, most models that are used professionally work from the Poisson...so it would just be great if someone could answer that question).